# Python regex to return all matching strings with comma seperated

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I'm looking for a regex to extract all the matching strings in a Dataframe column.

Ex:

```
Test_col_Name <br>
R2T.20.98.12 / New T7Y.10.35.10 <br>
G2O.16.18.02 / Use T7K.11.15.03<br>
A2U.10.18.15<br>
Test<br>
nan<br>
K9I.78.34.20<br>
test text P2I.67.78.99<br>
```

Can anyone please help me with regex to get all the matching items in new column as below?

```
Test_col_Name<br>
R2T.20.98.12,T7Y.10.35.10<br>
G2O.16.18.02,T7K.11.15.03<br>
A2U.10.18.15<br>
nan<br>
nan<br>
K9I.78.34.20<br>
P2I.67.78.99<br>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And can you please expand on your requirements. Future readers will have a hard time to get something out of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't full see the logic your going with but this could be a starting point

`df['col'].str.replace('/|New|Use|[T-t]est|text|', '').str.replace('  ', ',')`

```
0    R2T.20.98.12, T7Y.10.35.10 <br>
1     G2O.16.18.02, T7K.11.15.03<br>
2                   A2U.10.18.15<br>
3                               <br>
4                            nan<br>
5                   K9I.78.34.20<br>
6                   P2I.67.78.99<br>
```

Comment: I can replace words but they are not unique and I can get any  number of words in between or after the required text.